# Loss of data when using merge

Tags: r, merge

I have a df with states that I am trying to add lat, long values for each state so I can plot percent values for each state on a map. When I use merge I get either and empty df if I don't use

```
all=TRUE
```

Or I get missing data for either my lat, long values of my data itself depending on which I make x or y

Code to load my df and add column header

```
fileURL <- c("https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-jAX5hT2D3hNnVtLVhROENKRGs")
suppressMessages(require(data.table))
ge.planted <- fread(fileURL, na.strings = "NA")
colnames(ge.planted) <- c("region", "type", "crop", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
```

Code to get state names with lat, long values for the center of each state

```
snames <- data.frame(region=tolower(state.name), long=state.center$x, lat=state.center$y)
```

When I merge the two df using:

```
snames <- merge(ge.planted, snames, by="region")
```

I get

```
[1] region long   lat    type   crop   2000   2001   2002   2003   2004   2005   2006   2007   2008   2009   2010  
[17] 2011   2012   2013   2014   2015
```

Or if I use

```
snames <- merge( ge.planted, snames, by="region", all=TRUE)
```

And I get my values but no lat, long

```
  region                       type    crop 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
1:  Alabama Insect-resistant (Bt) only  Cotton    -    -    -    -    -   10   10   10   18   13   11   18   17   12
2:  Alabama    Herbicide-tolerant only  Cotton    -    -    -    -    -   28   25   25   15   18    7    4   11    4
3:  Alabama     Stacked gene varieties  Cotton    -    -    -    -    -   54   60   60   65   60   76   75   70   82
4:  Alabama           All GE varieties  Cotton    -    -    -    -    -   92   95   95   98   91   94   97   98   98
5: Arkansas    Herbicide-tolerant only Soybean   43   60   68   84   92   92   92   92   94   94   96   95   94   97
6: Arkansas           All GE varieties Soybean   43   60   68   84   92   92   92   92   94   94   96   95   94   97
   2014 2015 long lat
1:    9    4   NA  NA
2:    6    3   NA  NA
3:   83   90   NA  NA
4:   98   97   NA  NA
5:   99   97   NA  NA
6:   99   97   NA  NA
```

And finally with

```
snames <- merge(snames, ge.planted, by="region", all=TRUE)
```

I get lat, long but no values

```
      region long lat type crop 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
1    alabama  -87  33 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2     alaska -127  49 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3    arizona -112  34 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4   arkansas  -92  35 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5 california -120  37 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6   colorado -106  39 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

From best I can tell instead of merging the files based on 'region' it is appending the 'y' value on to the end of the data frame.

Comment: I've since tidy'd the df up gathering on the year and percent planted

Comment: your post is not reproducible as it is. You can use dput() to include your dataset (or a subset, enough to reproduce your problem) in your post.

Comment: `Error in fread(url, na.strings = "NA") :   Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch='h'`. (After replacing `fileURL` by `url`). `packageVersion("data.table")` is ‘1.9.6’

Comment: fixed issue with truncated name for fileURL

Comment: Your last two code lines are exactly the same but different output.

Comment: @Parfait copy/paste issue. its fixed now

Comment: One issue is use of to.lower, so that region names in one frame are different to the other (ge.planted has caps, snames dies not).  So merge will not recognize region names as equivalent

Comment: Removing tolowet() resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you used tolower(), so that region names in one frame are different to the other (ge.planted has caps, snames does not). So merge will not recognize region names as equivalent. Delete the tolower() call, and it should work.